# git config --list --global/--system/--local doesn't show the respective configs

Tags: git

git doesn't list global configs with `git config --list --global` and neither it does list local config with `git config --local`.Both the commands gives an error:

```
error: only one config file at a time.
```

It, however shows the global config with `git config --list`.
Even when i am in a git repo with its own config, doing `git config -l` lists only the global configs. Did i mess up anything?

I have my global config under `~/.config/git/gitconfig` and the Environment variable `GIT_CONFIG` points to it.

git version: 2.30.1

OS : arch linux

Comment: Based on [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIG), I think `GIT_CONFIG` is an override for the local config, so you shouldn't set it to the location of your global config.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in the comments, you don't have to specify explicitly `GIT_CONFIG`. To quickly fix this, you just have to `unset GIT_CONFIG` (and maybe remove it from your `.bashrc` if you've put it there). I believe that `GIT_CONFIG` is meant to be changed if your **local** configuration is not usually in its standard `.git/config` place.

If you need to specify exactly which config you want to list, do it with:

> -f config-file
>
> --file config-file
>
> Use the given config file instead of the one specified by GIT_CONFIG.

Answer (score 2):

To show global git config: `git config --list`

To show local git config: `git config --list --local`

Comment: AFAIK, `git config --list` will show all configuration values,whether they come from the system file (`/etc/gitconfig`), the (user's) global file (`~/.gitconfig`), or the local file (`./.git/config`). If a variable is defined both in a higher scope & in a lower scope (e.g. `credential.helper=foo` globally,but `credential.helper=bar` locally), only the lower-scope value will be in the `git config --list` output (`credential.helper=bar` in our example). To get the config values that come from the global file, use `git config --list --global`. For system config vals: `git config --list --system`.

Comment: Well, after looking at things, I need to fix something. With the `credential.helper=foo` being global and the `credential.helper=bar` being local, both will show up in the output of `git config --list`, but only the value given by the highest-precedence file will be used. That means that, if one were to run `git config --get credential.helper`, the output would be `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to consolidate and clarify the excellent answers from @mnesterov and @Sunil_Kumar_Das.

### Solution to OP's problem

It seems that the OP's problem was coming from the fact that the value (likely a filepath) in the environment variable, `GIT_CONFIG`, was overriding whatever values were in the local configuration file. The local configuration file is usually `<git-repo-root>/.git/config`.

So, what I've found, from experiment but not from documentation, is this:

The order in which configuration values get set (in order of reverse precedence), is

```
System, (usually from `/etc/gitconfig`, if it exists)
Global, (usually from `~/.gitconfig`, if it exists)
Local, (usually from `<git-repo-root>/.git/config
Custom, (from whichever file is specified in the GIT_CONFIG environment variable)
```

NOTE: only **one** of Local (x)or Custom will be read in. If both exist, Custom will be the one read in.

(It seems that @0x5453 has shared [some documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIG) in a comment.)

**Importantly**, the output of `git config --list` shows any config values set anywhere along the way. If a value gets overwritten by a file with higher precedence, both values will be in the output, but only the value given by the highest-precedence file will be used. (Examples will be coming.)

### Examples, Including Listing System, Global, Local, or Custom Config Values

Okay, so let's look at one of my repos. and see how this all works out.

#### Initial System Config Values

`git config --list --system` OR `git config --file /etc/gitconfig`

Note that, here as I start, I do not have an `/etc/gitconfig` file, but I will end up making one for demonstration purposes.

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list --system
fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list \
                                              --file /etc/gitconfig
fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ stat /etc/gitconfig
stat: cannot stat '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ sudo !!
sudo stat /etc/gitconfig
[sudo] password for bballdave025: 
stat: cannot stat '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #  -^- Made sure it's not -^- 
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+     just permissions
```

#### Initial Global Config Values

`git config --list --global` OR `git config --file ~/.gitconfig`

Here we go.

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list --global
user.name=bballdave025
user.email=bballdave025@USSHomestarrunner.com
credential.usehttppath=false
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list \
                                              --file ~/.gitconfig
user.name=bballdave025
user.email=bballdave025@USSHomestarrunner.com
credential.usehttppath=false
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

#### Initial Local Config Values

`cd <git-repo-root>` THEN

`git config --list --local` OR `git config --file .git/config`

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #  Let's make sure we
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ are in a git repo
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ root dir.
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ stat ./.git >/dev/null \
 && echo -e "\x23\x23\x23\x21\x21 In a git root dir \x21\x21\x23\x23\x23" \
 || echo -e "\x23\x23\x23\x21\x21 Not in a git root dir \x21\x21\x23\x23\x23"
###!! In a git root directory !!###
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #  I think we can do that
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ a bit more clearly, but
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ it will only tell us if
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ we are somewhere in a 
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ #+ git filetree
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git status
On branch feature_git-so-help
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature_git-so-help' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

If we weren't somewhere in a `git` filetree, our output would have been:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Okay, let's run the commands.

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/bballdave025/this-app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.feature_git-so-help.remote=origin
branch.feature_git-so-help.merge=refs/heads/feature_git-so-help
credential.usehttppath=true
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list --file ./.git/config
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/bballdave025/this-app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.feature_git-so-help.remote=origin
branch.feature_git-so-help.merge=refs/heads/feature_git-so-help
credential.usehttppath=true
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

#### Initial Custom Config Values

None. I'll illustrate this fact.

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ echo $GIT_CONFIG

bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

### Initial Output from `git config --list` and a Look at Overlapping Definitions

Note that I'll pipe output through `nl` to get pseudo-line-numbers and to make illustrating things easier.

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list | nl
     1  user.name=bballdave025
     2  user.email=bballdave025@USSHomestarrunner.com
     3  credential.usehttppath=false
     4  core.repositoryformatversion=0
     5  core.filemode=true
     6  core.bare=false
     7  core.logallrefupdates=true
     8  remote.origin.url=https://github.com/bballdave025/this-app.git
     9  remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    10  branch.development.remote=origin
    11  branch.development.merge=refs/heads/development
    12  branch.development-2022.remote=origin
    13  branch.development-2022.merge=refs/heads/development-2022
    14  credential.usehttppath=true
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

Note that line 3 shows `credential.usehttppath=false` (from the *global* `~/.gitconfig`), while line 14 shows `credential.usehttppath=true` (from the *local* `./.git/config`). We can see this more clearly with the command that follows. (Please forgive me, as I've cheated with the spacing.)

```
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config --list --show-origin | \
                                              nl | grep usehttppath
     3  file:/home/bballdave025/.gitconfig  credential.usehttppath=false
    14  file:.git/config                    credential.usehttppath=true
bballdave025@MYMACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

We can find out which one is *used* with

```
bballdave025@MY_MACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$ git config \
                                               --get credential.usehttppath
true
bballdave025@MY_MACHINE:~/my_repos/this-app$
```

We can see that the higher-precedence, local, later-in-the-output value has been applied.

### Some Changes for Illustration